# run python script and flask app at the same time

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create project that

1. Scrape data from the website automatically in every 5 minutes and save into db
2. Flask app interacts with user. User requests data from db

python script to scrape data would be like:

```
import os
import time

while True:
  os.system(scrape.py)
  time.sleep(5*60)
```

I originally tried to scrape data from the website every time the user requests data. But I fount out that it works so slowly.

So now I am trying to make another python script that scrapes data from website and save them into db automatically. And flask app just needs to get data from db.

My question is, how can I run both python script and flask app at the same time? Or is there any better way to handle the problem?

Answer (score 2):

With the use of `multithreading`, you can use a thread to handle scraping the data each five minutes and another thread to handle the flask app:

```
import threading
import os
import time
def scraping():
    while True:
        os.system(scrape.py)
        time.sleep(5*60)
def start_flask_app():
    #code
    pass
t1 = threading.Thread(target=scraping)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=start_flask_app)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

You should wrap your flask app inside of a function and make it a target for a thread and then you can start that thread along with the `scraping` thread also.

For more information on `multithreading` in python (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: Thank you! To my understanding, I think this is what Alexis meant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for these two components to run in the same process, or even in the same application. They can share some modules (e.g. object definitions), but you need one batch process that builds your database, and one flask app that serves user requests. Keep them loosely coupled and you will have many benefits, including simplicity and the possibility of replacing one component with something else in the future.

So set up your project over several files, and create one execution point (file) for the flask app and one execution point for the scraper.

Comment: Thanks, but I have another question for execution point. You mean create one .py file that will run both python script and run.py for flask app? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: There's no reason to create one .py file; you could do so, if you really want to, e.g. you could have a command-line option that determines which you do. But what for? It's simpler to just have two execution points, i.e. two files. They could be very short if most of the code is shared, but in this case I think you'll find that scraping and querying a resource are more different than they are alike.

Answer (score 0):

I think Flask-APScheduler would fit your usecase.

In your main application file, set up a scheduler (see https://viniciuschiele.github.io/flask-apscheduler/rst/usage.html for more details).

Import said scheduler from your main application, and set up a job with something along the lines of

```py
@scheduler.task('interval', id='scrape_task', seconds=300)
def scrape():
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Instead of just recommending a library, please [edit] your answer to include details on how Flask-APScheduler can be used to address the specific requirements of this question.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. New to answering.

Comment: yeah don't -1 one someone for trying to help you. Thats pretty toxic