# How can I access a variable inside a function in another python script

Tags: python, multithreading, function, variables, twilio

I have a file **textrecive.py** which contains the variable **body**

```
from threading import Thread
import mimetypes
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_reply():
    global body
    body = request.values.get('Body').lower()
    who = request.values.get('From').lower()
    print(who)
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    print(body)
    resp.message(input('what would you like to say'))

    return Response(str(resp), mimetype="application/xml"), body

while True:
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Thread(target = app.run()).start()
```

I would like to access the **body** variable in another script so I can be informed of what the message is saying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

I also wanted to add that I am using an **ngrok** server (Port:5000) to communicate between the python script/twilio api and my phone.

Comment: It's completely unrelated to the specific question you're asking, but that `while True` line should swap places with the `if __name__ == '__main__'`, or you'll loop forever doing nothing if you were to import this script.

Comment: maybe just have a `getBody()` function, import this function into the other script and run it.
`from textrecieve.py import getBody()` should work

Comment: I tried creating its own `getBody()` function, but I ended up receiving this error `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.`

Answer (score 1):

After researching for a while I came accross this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712988/run-python-script-and-flask-app-at-the-same-time)
which allows me to run the flask app and my script at the same time with the use of multithreading.